# Question on Morse lemma

Tags: analysis, algebraic-topology, morse-theory

I have this:

> (Page 421, heading Asymptotically quadratic functionals)
>
> *Remark 2.2.* (a) If $N$ is any neighbourhood of $x_0$, then the excision property of homology theory implies
>   $$C_k(f,x_0) \cong H_k(f^C \cap N, f^C \cap N - \{x_0\};R), \quad k\in\mathbb{Z}.$$
>   Using the Morse lemma, it follows that for a nondegenerate critical point $x_0$ with Morse index $\mu_0$, the critical groups are
>   $$C_k(f,x_0) \cong \delta_{k\mu_0} R = \begin{cases} R & \text{for } k=\mu_0; \\ 0 & \text{for } k\neq\mu_0. \end{cases}$$

I don’t understand how the Morse lemma is used here. Please could somebody explain?

Comment: Is this not a consequence of the fact that Morse lemma => non-degenerate critical points are isolated (hence you can choose an $N$ which contains no critical points) and Mayer Vietoris?

Comment: i dont understand you ?

Comment: The Morse lemma tells us that non-degenerate critical points of the function $f\colon M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are isolated and so in particular we can pick a neighbourhood $N$ small enough to contain no other critical points. In particular the set $U=N\setminus\{x_i|x_i\mbox{ is a critical point of }f\}$ is homotopy equivalent to a sphere of reasonable dimension. Now consider the Mayer-Vietoris sequence in homology of the subspaces $U$ and $V=M\setminus \{x_0\}$. I'm not fluent with Morse theory so I don't know if this LES gives the result you need.

Comment: and why there is the index of morse ?